# Is the Poincaré theorem valid for our universe?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, universe, poincare-recurrence

Poincaré tell us (roughly speaking) that any hamiltonian system come up arbitrarily close  to the initial condition if you wait enough time. 
For example, this theorem is valid for gases, and in general is one of the many key theorems that sustain Statistical Physics. 
And if this theorem is valid to cosmological level , what that implies?
I mean, at the end, the universe is just evolving along  the most probable line which could be one posible option of many more.

Comment: Poicare's reciprocity theorem contradicts the 2nd law of thermodynamics.

Comment: @Lelouch that should be an answer

Comment: The theorem does not apply, for instance, in an eternally expandig universe.

Comment: In the article linked by Lelouch in his answer below, there is a key point "The result applies to isolated mechanical systems subject to some constraints, e.g., all particles must be bound to a finite volume". We do not know if the Universe complies to such an assumption.

Comment: See also: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/255142/50583, http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/33772/50583

Comment: And let us insist that it is in no way one of the "many key theorems that sustain Statistical Physics". Even when applicable, the recurrence times are generally so huge as to be physically meaningless (for even moderately large systems).

Answer (score 0):

Poincare's recurrence theorem contradicts the second law of thermodynamics,which states that the entropy of an isolated system is non decreasing. The theorem suggests that a bounded dynamical system satisfying certain constraints, may return arbitrarily close to its initial state within some finite time. However, it is not necesary for all parts of a system to reach this arbitrarily close state at the same time. Physically this implies that various parts of the universe may revert back to the stages of the Big Bang after a long enough time, although the second law forbids such a situation.

For further reference,give the wikipedia article a read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_recurrence_theorem)

Comment: Maybe the Wiki's been edited since you typed this answer, but I can't see anything in it that refers to any "isolated system".  Elsewhere, I've read that Poincare recurrence applies only to "closed systems" (which include either the single universe prevalent in cosmological models prior to those of inflation, or each of the "local" or "bubble" or "pocket" universes" in one or another of the various models of an inflationary "multiverse").  Mersini-Houghton, a fan of QM's "Many Worlds Interpretation", feels that Poincare recurrence doesn't occur in a non-ergodic multiverse she's hypothesized.